# HLS stream created from webcam with ffmpeg is not displayed correctly

Tags: ffmpeg, video, hls

I want to create a HLS live stream from my webcam using ffmpeg.

I have this command which creates files used by HLS to stream the video in input.

```
sudo ffmpeg \
    -i path/to/video.mp4 \
    -preset slow \
    -f hls -hls_list_size 2 \
    -hls_flags independent_segments -hls_flags delete_segments \
    -hls_segment_type mpegts \
    -hls_segment_filename data%02d.ts \
    -master_pl_name master.m3u8 out1
```

When ran inside a folder served by a web server, I can watch the stream from an Android application using [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

I also have this command which takes my webcam input and place it into a video file.

```
ffmpeg \
    -f v4l2 -video_size 640x480 \
    -i /dev/video0 \
    output.mkv
```

I tried to combine both of these commands.
When I try to stream my webcam using HLS with the following command, the HLS files are being generated, but the display on the android app is wrong.

```
sudo ffmpeg \
    -f v4l2 -video_size 640x480 \
    -i /dev/video0 \
    -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -preset veryfast \
    -b:v 100M -b:a 128k \
    -f hls -hls_list_size 2 \
    -hls_flags independent_segments -hls_flags delete_segments \
    -hls_segment_type mpegts \
    -hls_segment_filename data%02d.ts \
    -master_pl_name master.m3u8 out1
```

The android app show a black screen with glitches.

I tried adding `-b:v 100M -b:a 128k` because the message `Bandwidth info not available, set audio and video bitrates`  was displayed by ffmpeg.

Then I tried adding `-c:v libx264 -crf 21 -preset veryfast` based on others HLS tutorial but the problem persists.

Because my two first command worked, I thought that ffmpeg understood the format of the input and output streams.

Why isn't the stream working properly ?

Edit1 : [Image showing the output on the ExoPlayer player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK1dv.jpg)

Edit2 :
The .m3u8 generated is readable with vlc.
The problem might come from ExoPlayer not understanding the format.
I'll close the post if it is the case.

Comment: Show the complete log from command #3. Guessing that you need to add `-vf format=yuv420p` output option. Log will verify. `-b:v` and `-crf` are mutually exclusive. Use only one or the other, but not both. Using both will result in `-b:v` being ignored (look at `rc=` in x264 info line in console output to confirm). With streaming you should almost always use `-b:v` with appropriate values for `-maxrate` and `-bufsize`. `-b:v 100M` is way too big: for standard def try `-b:v 2000k` or so at most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding -vf format=yuv420p to the command solved the issue.